# Shopify store translate into multiple languages

Tags: localization, shopify

Is it possible to change the shopify Language in client side.

I have 3 Language locale file. I want to translate based on client choice

is it possible to use below code to change my language.

```
{% assign shop.locale = 'fr' %}
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research, I realized that there was no "Plug and Play" solution available.

Creating one store per language would have been too expensive and requires you to somehow sync your stores.

A JavaScript solution does not supports SEO.

Shopify has a tool called langify using this we can do it but it has monthly recurring price I have added the link for your reference.
[Shopyify App store link](https://apps.shopify.com/langify)

Answer (score 1):

Seems there is no good enough solution, I have built this my own client-rendered solution. My solution provide:

- single domain
- not reload page on change language
- unlimited language
- unlimited page view
- FREE

  https://gist.github.com/Asoul/e5ee0a0f0ed17c93383ff47818b319c4

I open my source code above. I think this is some foundamatal infrastrcuture for an ec website, that's shameful to charge on this.

Hope these code can help some people.

But I think the perfect solution is that Shopify can offer a server-rendered method, not client rendered.